# Is SSO between non Auth0 website Auth0 secured API possible?

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, auth0

I need to enable SSO between my customer's website and my API.

The customers website doesn't use Auth0 but allow users to login using a few different social providers like Microsoft and Google.

My API is secured using Auth0 and also supports Microsoft and Google authentication via Auth0. If my customer sends the JWT token received when the user authenticated with Google with their request to my API, will Auth0 authenticate the user even though my customer doesn't use Auth0?

Answer (score 1):

Google/Microsoft auth is OAuth. OAuth is an explicit grant between the user and one particular application. It cannot and won't be shared with your app. The user would need to do a separate OAuth flow with your application to grant it access. There is no way around that.

However, given that this is an API, the more likely scenario is that the user shouldn't auth with your app at all, but rather, it should be the customer's application that auths and then works on behalf of the user. As such, you'd just set up the customer's application as a client and given them client credentials to use. Then, the user auths with the customer's website, the customer's website auths with your API via its client credentials, and then the user in effect works with your API via the customer's application as a go-between.

Answer (score 0):

No , if your api application is protected by Auth0 and use external providers , after authentication from external providers and back to Auth0 , Auth0 will validate the token issued by external provider ,decode token , read claims , issue Auth0's own token and implement session management . So that your api application only accepts tokens which issued by Auth0 and validate tokens use Auth0's key-pairs , it won't accept other provider's tokens .

You can make your client application and api application both secured by one identity provider(Auth0/Google/Microsoft) .